# Oracle Global Temporary table - Privileges for other instances

Tags: oracle, global, privileges

I have created Global Temporary table in oracle and inserting the data through my application, and its working fine for me when i connect to database with "system" as the username. Where as i have created one more user in the database with "user1" and have given "Grant all" privileges to this user also. Now when am connecting to database with "User1" as the username and running the application, the data is not inserting into Global temporary table. 
But when i try to insert data from sql developer tool its inserting.
With system user through application also working, whereas with user1 its not inserting. Am not getting whats behind going as am not that much DB expert.

Please have any idea suggest me. I have all privileges also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get an error message when user1 is doing the inserting? Or just don't see there data. Keep in mind data inserted by one user into a temp table isn't visible to any other user. And if the application is connection pooling, the database may think you have two different users accessing the data.

Comment: Data inserted by one session isn't visible to any other session, whether the other session is for the same user or not.

Comment: First suggestion, **stop using system**, as is explained in an answer to an unrelated problem here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6077226484122

Comment: Am not getting any error message, just am not seeing data. And data is inserting by one user only, so it has to be visible for that particular user. But am not able to see the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist, the table MUST be in other schema than SYS or SYSTEM. Create it on "User1".

Second, you must be sure that you select from the same table. Prefix the table with the schema when inserting and also when reading.

Also be sure that you are not in the situation of table created with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` and some `AUTOCOMMIT ON` in Sql Developer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got resolved the problem by placing the schema in front of the table in all queries.